# Shortcodes w/ Buddypress

Tags: buddypress, shortcode

I am trying to get a custom shortcode to display on forum topics and replies. I have test shortcode that works just fine on WordPress pages/posts. But, just cannot seem to get buddypress forum topics/replies to render them.

I looked over the docs on buddypress but nothing stood out as to possible cause or proper way to create a shortcode for buddypress.

Any help greatly appreciated.

As an example of code... This below snippet works in WordPress' pages/posts. But not for buddypress forum topics/replies.

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
 return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

User should be able to enter [foobar] for the shortcode and the expected result when rendered should be "foo and bar".